# Angular-7 How to navigate to certain section of the single page website

Tags: angular

Angular-7 How to navigate to a certain section of the single page website it's only navigating component only not section.

Comment: Please add more information or examples to the question description, because right now it's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to scroll to specific section you can use :

```
 let element = window.getElementById(elemId);
 element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```

refer [ScrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 0):

Are you navigating via router? Then you can navigate to components only.

- If you want to navigate to certain section then you can try some
  scrolling code by which you can move to that section.

Comment: well, once can suscribe to navigation changes, and scroll into view based on the params